# How to test response contains a particular key and value

Tags: python, django

The Django Rest Framework shows how to [test a response](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/) This is ok when you want to test the whole returned json. But if I just want to test that the response contains a particular **key** and **value** I tried this...

```
def test_get_user_shows_count(self):
            url = reverse('user_list')
            response = self.api_factory.get(url)
            self.assertContains(response, {'count': 1})
```

JSON Response

```
{
    'count': 1,
    'is_active': False,
    'url': 'http: //testserver/v1/user/95',
    'id': 95,
    'display_name': None
}
```

However, this fails, the only way I can get this to work is to put the full excepted json in, which I don't want to have to do. How can I test the above contains `count` and is eq to 1 only?

Comment: `self.assertContains(response.items(), ('count',1))`? Or `self.assertEqual(response.get("count"), 1)`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No assertContains would give an attribute 'status_code' error

Comment: How about  `self.assertEqual(response.content.data.get("count"),1)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about testing using `response.data`, as [suggested in the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#checking-the-response-data).

```
self.assertEqual(response.data['count'], 1)
```

If you really want to, you can use `json.loads` to convert the returned json back into a Python dict. However, all the extra work is doing is testing that DRF can convert `response.data` to JSON, which should already be tested elsewhere.

```
self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['count'], 1)
```

Comment: That would work with ``assertEqual`` not ``assertContains`` as this needs a status_code. However, I guess ``assertEqual`` is better in this case?

Comment: Yes, I used `assertContains` by mistake in my initial answer. Fixed now.